# Apex 5.1 interactive grid hiding toolbar buttons

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is it possible to allow add and save actions but hiding the "add row" and 'edit" buttons in the grid toolbar? When I tried unchecking those buttons I was not longer able to add data to the grid progrmmatically. How can I allow adding multiple rows programmatically and having "save" button but hiding "add row" and "edit"?

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this css to your page:

```
#myStaticIgId button[data-action="selection-add-row"], #myStaticIgId div[data-action="edit"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer. Is it in this place where you can create the function from the other question. But in another field, look at these options...

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! Is there a way to do the same to only one grid if there are multiple grids on the page?

Comment: yes, just add the id of your interactive gride at the beginning of each selector. I updated the code.