# Oracle APEX 5.1.1 Hiding toolbar Actions button

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement to edit my IG, but the customer does not want to see the "Actions" button. I have been experimenting with a variety of methods to hide the Actions button using CSS (based on the StackOverflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681118/apex-5-1-interactive-grid-hiding-toolbar-buttons)) and using javascript based on John Snyders [Hacking the IG](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/24/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-2/) article and the blog post [here](https://placehyperbolehere.com/blog/) but have not been successful.

The CSS code I've used is

```
#load_sheet button[id="load_sheet_ig_actions_button"] {
  display: none !important
}
```

where #load_sheet is the static_id name the IG region. I'm using the button id as there is no data-action available as described in the article above.

I've also tried placing the following javascript code in the IG Advanced attribute:

```
function(config) {
  var $ = apex.jQuery;
  var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();
  config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
  // toolbarData[3] is the actions1 (Action button) array
  toolbarData[3]['hide'] = true;
  return config;
}
```

Is there a way of hiding the "Actions" button while still showing the "Edit" and "Save" buttons?

Thanks for any assist or ideas.

Comment: #load_sheet_toolbar_actions_button {
   display: none !important;
} you need to put that code on your page properties in the field "css inline". Your css should works too, but only this is necessary.

Comment: But is better using javascript to config your IG, Because using css you are linking your CSS to that selector, if it changes your css it will also have to change ...

Comment: I concur - I'd prefer to use javascript, but the method I'm using I think is insufficient; I'm guessing there isn't a 'hide' property for the Action button. Any alternatives would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a propertie to set that button to be invisible, but I can't found.

But, toolbarData is an array, so you can remove that button from this array, in this case that button will not be rendered, your code should look like this:

```
function(config) {    
    var $ = apex.jQuery;
    var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();
    toolbarData.splice(3,1); //remove actions button
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;

    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question. Sorry for the late response.

This works fine for me:

```
#eng_req_ig_toolbar_actions_button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

where eng_req is the static_id name the IG region.